# Voice to text app for Messaging ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sms, voice-recognition

I am using stock ICS 4.0.4 on my phone and it seems to be missing a utility which I have seen on other Android phones with ICS. It doesn't have the option for `voice to text` native app for messaging.

How can I activate it?

**Note: I do not have an always active internet connection**

Comment: What phone do you have?

Comment: Under input methods do you have google voice typing?

Comment: no there is not.

Comment: Do you have Google [Voice Search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch&feature) installed?

Comment: I installed it before but it requires internet access all the time which I don't ahve

Comment: Up until Jellybean (4.1/2) Voice typing requires an active internet connection as all of the voice processing is done in the cloud. In Jellybean they added offline voice typing.